# Refactor random datetime on Python

Tags: python, random

I accept suggestions to improve this code

https://github.com/rg3915/django-orm/blob/master/fixtures/gen_random_values.py#L34-L45

```
import random
import datetime

def gen_timestamp(min_year=1915, max_year=1996):
    # gera um datetime no formato yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000000
    year = random.randint(min_year, max_year)
    month = random.randint(11, 12)
    day = random.randint(1, 28)
    hour = random.randint(1, 23)
    minute = random.randint(1, 59)
    second = random.randint(1, 59)
    microsecond = random.randint(1, 999999)
    date = datetime.datetime(
        year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond).isoformat(" ")
    return date
```

Accept Pull Request

https://github.com/rg3915/django-orm/issues/1

Comment: So what's your question? Doesn't your code work?

Comment: Works yes, just wanted to improve.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the repeated calls to `random.randint` by only generating the `microsecond` offset across the complete time range, and then using `timedelta` to add that offset to the initial date in 1915.

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Answer (score 0):

```
def gen_timestamp(min_year=1915, max_year=1996):
    min_date = datetime(min_year,  1,1)
    max_date = datetime(max_year+1,1,1)
    delta = random()*(max_date - min_date).total_seconds()
    return (min_date + timedelta(seconds=delta)).isoformat(" ")
```